# Why bowsers cannot download files to storage (path looks /dev/null/Download)?

Tags: internal-storage, file-system, storage, partitions, internal-sd

The phone is [Samsung Galaxy Note N7000](https://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_note_n7000-4135.php). For the last few years I use [NightOwl](https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-note/development/rom-nightowl-preview-t3455847) custom rom (Android 7). I do not remember when I faced with this problem, maybe after repartitioning with [REPIT](https://github.com/Lanchon/REPIT/issues/98#issuecomment-550546613) (but author says that probably not), but now I cannot make photos - photo app says that I need to insert SD card, but I can make photos through the Evernote app. Also in WhatsUp I cannot see photos because my phone cannot download them, and web browsers cannot download any file. But I can install most of the programs, and for example Evernote cache my notes.

Inside recovery mode, in TWRP, I found that I have partition `sdcard1` that is 0 bytes in size. Maybe if I remove this partition it will fix my storage problem?

[image]
[image]
[image]

I tried to flash the same ROM again.
I asked in thread about this ROM, but nobody answered. The phone is without external SD card. When in `Settings` I open `Storage` - it crash.

`logcat -b all | grep -iE 'vold|storage'`: [log](https://gist.github.com/vitaly-zdanevich/44ad5eda190f114f5fc73cbac0334f4a).

`/proc/last_kmsg` and `dmesg`: [log](https://gist.github.com/vitaly-zdanevich/50101bb2f2d9e46cb97488df72f50513).

`mount` returned:

```
rootfs on / type rootfs (ro,seclabel,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev type tmpfs (rw,seclabel,nosuid,relatime,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,seclabel,relatime,mode=600)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,relatime)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,seclabel,relatime)
selinuxfs on /sys/fs/selinux type selinuxfs (rw,relatime)
none on /acct type cgroup (rw,relatime,cpuacct)
tmpfs on /mnt type tmpfs (rw,seclabel,relatime,mode=755,gid=1000)
none on /dev/memcg type cgroup (rw,relatime,memory)
none on /dev/cpuctl type cgroup (rw,relatime,cpu)
/dev/block/mmcblk0p9 on /system type ext4 (ro,seclabel,noatime,user_xattr,barrier=1,data=ordered)
/dev/block/mmcblk0p7 on /cache type ext4 (rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noatime,errors=panic,user_xattr,barrier=1,journal_async_commit,data=ordered)
/dev/block/mmcblk0p1 on /efs type ext4 (rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noatime,user_xattr,barrier=1,journal_async_commit,data=ordered)
/dev/block/mmcblk0p10 on /data type ext4 (rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noatime,errors=panic,user_xattr,barrier=1,journal_async_commit,data=ordered,noauto_da_alloc)
tmpfs on /storage type tmpfs (rw,seclabel,relatime,mode=755,gid=1000)
/sys/kernel/debug on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,seclabel,relatime)
/dev/block/vold/public:179_11 on /mnt/media_rw/S}M-^^M-~4M-9^DK $t type vfat (rw,dirsync,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,uid=1023,gid=1023,fmask=0007,dmask=0007,allow_utime=0020,codepage=cp437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/block/vold/public:179_11 on /mnt/secure/asec type vfat (rw,dirsync,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,uid=1023,gid=1023,fmask=0007,dmask=0007,allow_utime=0020,codepage=cp437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/fuse on /mnt/runtime/default/S}M-^^M-~4M-9^DK $t type fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,user_id=1023,group_id=1023,default_permissions,allow_other)
/dev/fuse on /storage/S}M-^^M-~4M-9^DK $t type fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,user_id=1023,group_id=1023,default_permissions,allow_other)
/dev/fuse on /mnt/runtime/read/S}M-^^M-~4M-9^DK $t type fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,user_id=1023,group_id=1023,default_permissions,allow_other)
/dev/fuse on /mnt/runtime/write/S}M-^^M-~4M-9^DK $t type fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,user_id=1023,group_id=1023,default_permissions,allow_other)
```

`blkid`:

```
/dev/block/zram0: UUID="da191bea-c7ca-4b27-af09-ce87c7f99943" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/block/mmcblk0p1: UUID="57f8f4bc-abf4-0000-675f-946fc0f9f25b" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/block/mmcblk0p7: UUID="57f8f4bc-abf4-655f-bf67-946fc0f9f25b" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/block/mmcblk0p9: LABEL="system" UUID="da594c53-9beb-f85c-85c5-cedf76546f7a" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/block/mmcblk0p10: UUID="57f8f4bc-abf4-655f-bf67-946fc0f9f25b" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/block/mmcblk0p11: LABEL="S}M-^^M-~4M-9^DK $t" UUID="7F73-0B1A" TYPE="vfat" 
/dev/block/mmcblk0p12: UUID="49f005e2-2f62-448b-9ba1-3e4da2ee1b41" TYPE="ext4"
```

`# cat fstab.smdk4210`:

```
# Android fstab file.
#<src>                                      <mnt_point>             <type>    <mnt_flags and options>                                   <fs_mgr_flags>
# The filesystem that contains the filesystem checker binary (typically /system) cannot
# specify MF_CHECK, and must come before any filesystems that do specify MF_CHECK
# data partition must be located at the bottom for supporting device encryption

/dev/block/mmcblk0p9                        /system                 ext4      ro,noatime                                                wait
/dev/block/mmcblk0p7                        /cache                  ext4      noatime,nosuid,nodev,journal_async_commit,errors=panic    wait,check,formattable
/dev/block/mmcblk0p7                        /cache                  f2fs      noatime,nosuid,nodev,inline_data,inline_xattr,discard     wait,check,formattable
/dev/block/mmcblk0p1                        /efs                    ext4      noatime,nosuid,nodev,journal_async_commit,errors=panic    wait,check,notrim
/dev/block/mmcblk0p10                       /data                   ext4      noatime,nosuid,nodev,noauto_da_alloc,journal_async_commit,errors=panic    wait,check,formattable,encryptable=/efs/metadata
/dev/block/mmcblk0p10                       /data                   f2fs      noatime,nosuid,nodev,inline_data,inline_xattr,discard     wait,check,formattable,encryptable=/efs/metadata
# /dev/block/mmcblk0p12                       /preload                ext4      noatime,nosuid,nodev,journal_async_commit                 wait

# vold-managed volumes ("block device" is actually a sysfs devpath)
/devices/platform/dw_mmc/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0*     auto    auto    defaults        voldmanaged=sdcard0:11,nonremovable,noemulatedsd
/devices/platform/s3c-sdhci.2/mmc_host/mmc1*     auto    auto    defaults        voldmanaged=sdcard1:auto,encryptable=userdata
/devices/platform/s3c_otghcd/usb*                auto    auto    defaults        voldmanaged=usb:auto

# recovery
/dev/block/mmcblk0p5                        /boot                   emmc      defaults      recoveryonly
/dev/block/mmcblk0p6                        /recovery               emmc      defaults      recoveryonly

# zRAM
/dev/block/zram0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Inside recovery mode, in TWRP, I found that I have partition `sdcard1` that is 0 bytes in size. Maybe if I remove this partition it will fix my storage problem?

In TWRP there's also USB OTG which would also be 0 bytes in size. Both are just mount points where external SD card and USB OTG are mounted (if available). This isn't relevant to your problem, neither you can remove this partition (because it's not a partition).

The root cause of problem seems to be the bad filesystem label you set on `mmcblk0p11` partition. `vold` includes filesystem label (or UUID or serial number) in mount path, which the processes are unable to read.

`blkid`:

```
dev/block/mmcblk0p11: LABEL="S}M-^^M-~4M-9^DK $t" UUID="7F73-0B1A" TYPE="vfat"
```

`mount`:

```
/dev/block/vold/public:179_11 on /mnt/media_rw/S}M-^^M-~4M-9^DK $t type vfat (rw,dirsync,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,uid=1023,gid=1023,fmask=0007,dmask=0007,allow_utime=0020,codepage=cp437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/fuse on /storage/S}M-^^M-~4M-9^DK $t type fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,user_id=1023,group_id=1023,default_permissions,allow_other)
```

`vold`:

```
11-06 02:25:53.173  2901  2968 D VoldConnector: RCV <- {654 public:179_11 S}M-^^M-~4M-9^DK $t}
11-06 02:25:53.173  2901  2968 D VoldConnector: RCV <- {656 public:179_11 /mnt/media_rw/S}M-^^M-~4M-9^DK $t}
11-06 02:25:53.174  2901  2968 D VoldConnector: RCV <- {655 public:179_11 /storage/S}M-^^M-~4M-9^DK $t}
```

Characters in string: `S}M-^^M-~4M-9^DK $t}` seem to be non-printable. E.g. `^M` denotes *Carriage Return* which is used with *Line Feed* to print new line character (next line) on Windows (`CR LF`).

You can fix the filesystem label using `fatlabel` from [dosfstools](https://github.com/dosfstools/dosfstools) or `mlabel` from [mtools](https://www.gnu.org/software/mtools). Boot in recovery, un-mount all partitions and do:

```
~# fatlabel -r /dev/block/mmcblk0p11
```

Or set label manually:

```
~# fatlabel /dev/block/mmcblk0p11 sdcard
```

Or you can format the partition, but it's not clear from your provided information what filesystem it is. I suppose it's FAT32. So either go to *Advanced Wipe* --> *Repair or Change Filesystem*, select the partition, select FAT32 (if supported by TWRP) and format. Or from commandline do:

```
~# mkfs.fat -F32 /dev/block/mmcblk0p11
```

Or with label:

```
~# mkfs.fat -n sdcard -F32 /dev/block/mmcblk0p11
```

Use `-F16` option or `mkfs.vfat` for FAT16 or vFAT filesystems. Generally all use `vfat` driver.

In all cases make sure to select right partition otherwise **YOU MAY GET YOUR DEVICE PERMANENTLY BRICKED**.

Or flash factory firmware if available. Note that all data will be erased.

Comment: Thank you, formatted through the TWRP and now I am happy :)

Comment: In my case it was `mkfs.vfat`.